# How do i transition between different roots?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, transition, root

I am trying to transition between two sets of roots. I wrote the code to change the roots however I don't know how to create the transition, so it fades into the new colors.
I wrote this code:

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');

var i = 0;

setInterval(changeColor, 4000);
    function changeColor() {
        if (i < 1) {i++} else {i = 0};
        console.log(i)
            if (i == 0) {
                const setVariables = vars => Object.entries(vars).forEach(v => root.style.setProperty(v[0], v[1]));
                const myVariables = {
                  '--gradColor1': '#eff6ff',
                  '--gradColor2': '#dbeafe',
                  '--gradColor3': '#bfdbfe',
                  '--gradColor4': '#93c5fd',
                  '--gradColor5': '#60a5fa',
                };
                setVariables(myVariables);
            } else if (i == 1){
                const setVariables = vars => Object.entries(vars).forEach(v => root.style.setProperty(v[0], v[1]));
                const myVariables = {
                  '--gradColor1': '#23019b',
                  '--gradColor2': '#4b34a0',
                  '--gradColor3': '#60339e',
                  '--gradColor4': '#630d5d',
                  '--gradColor5': '#5d0742',
                };
                setVariables(myVariables);
            }
    }
```

It works, however, I would like a 1-second transition, and the code is not pretty. Please help!:)